# Select the first input group item on input focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am trying to select the first input group addon when the input box is focused.

I have tried so far but managed to only select the second input group item.

Here is my HTML

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.form-control:focus+.input-group-addon {
  color: #f00 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Focus on me</h3>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
  </div>

  <hr>
  <h4>Please help!!!</h4>
  <p>I want to change the color of the first input group addon and not the second</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to maintain the same HTML structure that you have currently, you're going to have to move up in the DOM to modify that addon element that you specified. This is going to require Javascript.

Using Javascript, we want to check whether the element is in focus or blurred. We can do this using either inline `onfocus` and `onblur` or just by adding event listeners.

Once you add the listeners, you need to find the element that you want to change in relation to the current element and update it depending on whether it is blurred or in focus.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('.input-group input.form-control');

// On element focus
input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  var container = input.parentNode;
  var addon = container.querySelector('.input-group-addon');
  
  addon.style.color = 'red';
});

// On element blur
input.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  var container = input.parentNode;
  var addon = container.querySelector('.input-group-addon');
  
  addon.style.color = 'black';
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h3>Focus on me</h3>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
  </div>

  <hr>
  <h4>Please help!!!</h4>
  <p>I want to change the color of the first input group addon and not the second</p>
</div>
```

My example could be compressed, but it serves as the general idea of what you need to do to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Not with the current structure of the HTML in a way that will also work with Bootstrap. I'll see if I can cook something up when I get time though.

Comment: Cool, I have used JavaScript code you provided but modified to add and remove given classes